# Digital signals have two states or interger values

Tags: digital-logic

Some people have the concept that digital signals are in the form of 0's and 1's.
But in a book i got the concept that digital signals can have integer values. Which concept is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up the ideas of *digital* signals with *binary* signals.

A digital signal is one that takes only discrete values, or, in the real world, one in which we distinguish only a discrete set of values. It might have 2 possible values, or 3, or 10, or whatever.

A *binary* signal is a specific case of a digital signal that takes two different values.

A [*ternary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_computer) digital signal can take three different values.

In communications, we often use complex modulation schemes that can take one of many different values in each baud interval. For example, [quadrature amplitude modulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_amplitude_modulation) (QAM) systems might allow 16, 64, 256, or more different values.

A clock can have a digital display without any binary logic being involved in its design:

[image]
(image source: theclockgallery.com)

Comment: Or indeed any electricity at all... https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/Jumphour.jpg

Answer (score 1):

\$n\$ bits (either 0s and 1s) can be combined to code intergers in then range \$0..2^n-1\$. So both statements are true.

That's just like in the decimal system several digits (either 0s, 1s, 2s, .. or 9s) can be combined to code integers in the range \$0..10^n-1\$.

Note that it is not possible to code any interval of *real* numbers by a finite number of bits/digits.

Answer (score 1):

A digital signal is measured in volts with a logic 1 typically being 3.3 volts or 5 volts and logical zero being 0 volts. So, a digital signal can be regarded as having logical values (i.e. 0 or 1) but also can be regarded as having real values such as 0V and 3.3 volts.

A combination of digital signals can be regarded as a binary number of several digits in length. Under these circumstances the basic interpretation of the binary value is that of an integer BUT, the designer of the "system" can be representing non-integer values such as fractions or any other conceivable counting system.